# How make the turning of the player happens only at edges or desired places in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am trying to make a game where player runs to collect the coins. The problem I am facing here is the player turning left and right. I want the player to turn only at specific places and not everywhere. I have no idea how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like Temple Run right?

Let the character run. The character's controller should have "turn right/left" deactivated. On each path intersection (where character should turn a side), you add an collider (a cube). When character collides it, you active the right/left movement detector. On collider exit, you can deactivate it.

If you dont want bugs/glitch like: 2 tap on left, turn twice, then you just deactivate the flag when player turned once.

If you want a smooth camera turn, you can use Camera Scripts, and iTween for the player (tweening only the y-axis rotation +90 -90)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you all for helping me out.. i did the same thing of placing the  colliders with trigger turned on and the player can turn only when he is inside that collider.. but it is not smooth going in device.. so i want the character to turn only when he is 0.2 distance from the collider how to achieve this ?? help me with the code.. i want my player to turn exactly like the player in temple run turns..

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want the player to move only forward until they reach a specific point, after which they have the option to turn.

You can achieve this by constraining the players movement through script (make them only move along the Z axis for example) and only allow them to turn when they reach that specific point.

you can detect that the player reached that point by placing a collider on the point (and setting it to is Trigger), and then handling in the script.

Goodluck

Comment: Then they should be able to turn and walk back afterwards. I like the idea of walking to a point though!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a map, you can place empty gameobjects in the scene. Attack Collission detectors to them, make sure they create large walls. If the player walks through, switch the the possibility of him turning accordingly.

It's quite some work though, but you can attack the same script to every invisible wall.

Comment: i want my turn to happen inside the collider with trigger on but the turn input should be given before the player reaches the collider like 0.2 distance from the collider how to achieve this.. ?? the snippet i am using here is,                                             void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  if(other.gameObject.tag=="Turn"){
   isTurningLeft=true;
   isTurningRight=true;
  }

Comment: i want my turn to happen inside the collider with trigger on but the turn input should be given before the player reaches the collider like 0.2 distance from the collider how to achieve this.. ?? please guide me..the snippet i am using here is,if(isTurningLeft){
    if(isLeft){transform.Rotate(0,-90 * Time.deltaTime,0);
isTurningLeft=false; }}
if(isTurningRight){if(isRight){transform.Rotate(0,90 * Time.deltaTime,0);isTurningRight=false;  }}      void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{if(other.gameObject.tag=="Turn"){isTurningLeft=true;isTurningRight=true;}

Comment: I'd use a Raycast for that. I've read your comment on the other answer. You say it's not going smooth. What isn't going smooth?

Comment: on device if i make a swipe to make the player turn, only sometimes its turning. Its not accurate. Wat i want is if i make a swipe even before the player enters the collider it should turn inside the collider. to be precise if the player is 0.5 distance away from the tagged collider and if i make a swipe then player should travel the 0.5 distance and then turn automatically.. how to achieve this help me with the code to save me..

Comment: You can use `Vector3.Distance` to get the distance from the one to the other object.

Comment: i am not getting how to use the vector3.distance, because here i am taking the tagged object name and measuring the distance between the player and that tagged object.. how to achieve this ?? iam using c# for this. Please help me with the code..

Comment: I'd like to help you but I think your code is structured wrong. You ask me for code (without showing what you have already tried) to solve a problem, but I don't think correct code solves your original problem...

Comment: if(isTurningLeft){ if(isLeft){transform.Rotate(0,-90 * Time.deltaTime,0); isTurningLeft=false; }} if(isTurningRight){if(isRight){transform.Rotate(0,90 * Time.deltaTime,0);isTurningRight=false; }} void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {if(other.gameObject.tag=="Turn"){isTurningLeft=true;isTurningRight=true;} this is the code iam using.. now it is turning only when it is inside the tagged trigger and swipe has been performed.. what i want is wen the swipe has been perform before the player entering the trigger i want the player to to wait and then turn inside the collider..

Comment: hello RakeshChatra I am also looking for a smooth turn like temple run did you find any solution of that?

Comment: @hariszaman http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/31644/making-objects-turn-smoothly.html